# Does a continuous function map a bounded sequence to a bounded sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, compactness

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous function. Does $f$ map every bounded sequence to a bounded sequence?

Since we are talking about bounded sequence, so maybe we can take $\{1/n\}$ in $(0,1)$. It is bounded here. If we take continuous function $x\mapsto \dfrac 1x$, it would map the sequence to $\{n\}$, which is unbounded.

So I guess the answer to the given question should be No. But answer key says Yes.

Comment: It's important that the function is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$. A bounded sequence is contained in an interval $[-K,K]$ for some $K$. Then you should know a theorem guaranteeing that $f([-K,K])$ is bounded.

Comment: If $f$ is not bounded, $f((x_n))$ could not to be bounded.

Comment: But can we say 1/x is discontinuous at 0. Don't we discuss discontinuity when left hand and right hand limits mismatch. Since here LHL is out of question, so RHL can be anything, can it not be?

Comment: Also I get that if the domain was a closed interval, we would have got a bounded sequence. Since domain is R. So maybe we can discuss open interval as well?

Comment: No. 1/x  is not defined  at 0

Comment: Ok, sorry, my mistake. Got it. However I still wonder why we are considering closed interval.

Comment: @DanielFischer Is the theorem that continuous functions achieve their max on a closed interval?

Comment: @Alephnull And minimum; aka extreme value theorem. Or that the continuous image of a quasicompact set is again quasicompact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a_n)$ be a bounded sequence. Then there exists a closed interval $[p,q]$ such that $a_n\in[p,q]$, for all $n$.

Since $f$ is continuous, the image of the compact set $[p,q]$ is a closed and bounded set (and also an interval, actually).

---

Why does this fail for the sequence $(1/n)$ and $f(x)=1/x$, over $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$? There is no closed and bounded interval $[p,q]$ cointained in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ such that $1/n\in[p,q]$, for all $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, the answer is yes. The map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, it is only continuous over $\mathbb{R}_{-}^* $ or $\mathbb{R}_{+}^*$, this is why close to $0$ a problem arises.

Suppose $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a real bounded sequence and that $f$ is a continuous function **over all** $\mathbb{R}$. Then, if $M$ is a positive real number such that $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}, x_n \in [-M,M]$, then, for all positive integers $n$, you must have $f(x_n) \in f\left( [-M,M] \right)$ which is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ since $f$ is continuous. Therefore $\left(f(x_n)\right)$ is bounded.

Comment: But if we taken open interval ( which is also bounded), then we might not guarantee the boundedness of the function?

Comment: It would have been also the same because, since $f$ is continuous on all $\mathbb{R}$, you can embed your open interval into a bigger closed one, and the rest of the proof is exactly the same